# Add style to javafx.scene.layout.VBox dynamically from CSS string

Tags: java, css, javafx-2, stylesheet

I'm working with JavaFX 2 and have a VBox. I know I can add a stylesheet through .getStylesheets().add("file.css"), but if I have the content of file.css in a String, how do I add it to the VBox?

Comment: I don't think there is any public API for supplying a stylesheet content from a String, I think you would need to [hack the source code](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Main) to allow that to happen.

Comment: Not sure if I get the question. If by the contents of a CSS file you mean a set of CSS classes, then the answer is indeed no. If you mean a set of CSS rules, you might want to check out Node#setStyle(String)

Comment: Would it be possible instead to add a set of CSS classes from a string to a FXMLLoader? For example FXMLLoader x = new FXMLLoader(); x.setController(..); x.setStylesheet(my_css_string); x.load(...); Not sure if I should make this another question.